# order confirmation emails are not working for admin & buyer

Tags: magento-1.9, email, ce-1.9.1.0

we are not getting order confirmation email to admin account, also for buyer.
but registration email is working for buyer.

```
2016-05-23T16:30:05+00:00 ERR (3): 
exception 'Zend_Mail_Transport_Exception' with message 'Unable to send mail. ' in /home/site/public_html/lib/Zend/Mail/Transport/Sendmail.php:137
Stack trace:
#0 /home/site/public_html/lib/Zend/Mail/Transport/Abstract.php(348): Zend_Mail_Transport_Sendmail->_sendMail()
#1 /home/site/public_html/lib/Zend/Mail.php(1194): Zend_Mail_Transport_Abstract->send(Object(Zend_Mail))
#2 /home/site/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Queue.php(241): Zend_Mail->send()
#3 [internal function]: Mage_Core_Model_Email_Queue->send(Object(Mage_Cron_Model_Schedule))
#4 /home/site/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Cron/Model/Observer.php(325): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#5 /home/site/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Cron/Model/Observer.php(72): Mage_Cron_Model_Observer->_processJob(Object(Mage_Cron_Model_Schedule), Object(Mage_Core_Model_Config_Element))
#6 /home/site/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1338): Mage_Cron_Model_Observer->dispatch(Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#7 /home/site/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1317): Mage_Core_Model_App->_callObserverMethod(Object(Mage_Cron_Model_Observer), 'dispatch', Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#8 /home/site/public_html/app/Mage.php(448): Mage_Core_Model_App->dispatchEvent('default', Array)
#9 /home/site/public_html/cron.php(75): Mage::dispatchEvent('default')
#10 {main}
```

we entered email address in `Send Order Email Copy` To under `Sales emails`

Comment: use this extension https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/smtp-pro-email-free-custom-smtp-email.html its very easy to you to handle

Comment: @Charlie it was problem with only paypal payment method. from other payment methods we are getting mail.